# I have made a Pygame program but when the sprites overlap it has a white outline on some of them

Tags: python, sprite, pygame

I am making a level editor for a game I am working on. I have it set up so that you can put a picture in a folder and it will split it from a 90x90 pix block to 9 30x30 pix blocks that can be used in the editor. The code that makes the 30x30 blocks looks like this:

```
    one = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,255,0))
    two = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,255,0))
    three = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,2550,0))
    four = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,255,0))
    five = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,255,0))
    six = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,2550,0))
    seven = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,2550,0))
    eight = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,255,0))
    nine = Image.new('RGBA',(30,30),(255,255,255,0))

    for y in range(1,iy):
        print ((y/9)*10),"%"
        for x in range(1,ix):
            pixel = im.getpixel((x,y))
            if y<30:
                if x<30:
                    one.putpixel((x,y),pixel)
                elif x<60:
                    four.putpixel((x-30,y),pixel)
                else:
                    seven.putpixel((x-60,y),pixel)
            elif y <60:
                if x <30:
                    two.putpixel((x,y-30),pixel)
                elif x <60:
                    five.putpixel((x-30,y-30),pixel)
                else:
                    eight.putpixel((x-60,y-30),pixel)
            else:
                if x < 30:
                    three.putpixel((x,y-60),pixel)
                elif x < 60:
                    six.putpixel((x-30,y-60),pixel)
                else:
                    nine.putpixel((x-60,y-60),pixel)
    add = [im,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]
    bdict[s]= add
    cd = os.getcwd()+'\\'+s +'\\'
    one.save(cd + s +'one.png')
    two.save(cd+s+'two.png')
    three.save(cd+s+'three.png')
    four.save(cd+s+'four.png')
    five.save(cd+s+'five.png')
    six.save(cd+s+'six.png')
    seven.save(cd+s+'seven.png')
    eight.save(cd+s+'eight.png')
    nine.save(cd+s+'nine.png')
    im.save(cd + fol)
    im = os.getcwd()+'\\'+fol
    one = os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'one.png'
    two =os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'two.png'
    three =os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'three.png'
    four = os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'four.png'
    five =os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'five.png'
    six =os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'six.png'
    seven =os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'seven.png'
    eight =os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'eight.png'
    nine =os.getcwd()+'\\'+s+'nine.png'
    add = [im,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]           
    bdict[s]= add
    maxes[0]+=1
```

when two blocks overlap, they have this strange white bar that only shows up around the top left and right blocks and the bottom left and right blocks. That looks like this:
[image: overlap error]

The only other place that might have the error is where the code loads the sprites, here:
grounds is an array containing the different rectangles while gsprites is an array containing the different sprites in the format that they are loaded by Pygame.

```
for number in range(0,len(grounds)):
    cr = grounds[number]
    cr.left += xscroll
    cr.top += yscroll
    pygame.draw.rect(windowsurface,clear,cr)
    change = pygame.transform.scale(gsprites[number],(30,30))
    windowsurface.blit(gsprites[number],cr)
    cr.left -= xscroll
    cr.top -= yscroll
```

I am running windows vista 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. I was drawing a rect before I blitted the sprite, and it ended up showing up under the sprite.

Comment: Make sure you click accept on you own answer so we know it's an answered question :)

Comment: I'm trying but it says I still have to wait another 23 hours

Comment: oh alright then. It's not REALLY important, it just helps people find questions that still need answers so we can help out. No hurry :)